# Tokbox - Archive Not Found or Invalid URI

Tags: video, asp.net-mvc-2, opentok, tokbox

Please note we are using tokbox for video recording.

Sometimes it works fine but sometime it give errors, there are two types of errors we get..

1. Archive Not Found
2. Invalid URI (Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined) error we get.

If we try to check the archive id from browser at http://digitaltsai.com/ot/tester/  as written in http://tokbox.com/forums/archiving/archive-not-found-t9580
we get the archive.

But when i try to get archive by code

```
response = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(); , major times I get errors...
```

Below is the XML we are getting.

```
<Errors>
<error code="404">
<itemNotFound message="Archive 8e7db9c9-6d31-4f57-8bd1-bd3bdf7fea8b not found" />
</error>
</Errors>
```

Please help us to resolve the issue asap, since **my portal is already live and facing major issues because of it**.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get the "archive not found" error, you probably have an invalid token. If you supply a token that doesn't have the right credentials, you will get the 404 error.

To test this, please print out what token you're trying to get the archive with. You can also hardcode a token and see that it works everytime.

Comment: I have tried to hardcore token, but still facing problem.             I have also stored the token, archive id each time, to test it in tester at 
http://digitaltsai.com/ot/tester/ nd                          sometimes when program gives error, the tester may run it successfully, or sometimes the tester also does not load the recorded video.

Any idea in this scenario?